# Symfony/propel: new line in text in propel schema, how?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have this:

```
SediI18n:
   XXXXXX:   { id: sede_foo_1, culture: it, paese_indirizzo: it,
ufficio: "Ufficio di XXX 1", indirizzo: "Foo Bar FooBar" }
```

Now, when i prints this register the field "indirizzo":

> Foo Bar FooBar

Everything is in one line.

Any way to write the value of "indirizzo" to print directly in my web
page something like this below?

```
Foo
Bar
FooBar
```

Javi

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding `\n` in your string, and see whether they make it into the database. You could also try [block literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Block_literals) by starting the string with a `|` character, which allows you to span multiple lines, but that might break the generated insert clause.

Then, to convert your newlines to `<br/>` tags, use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) when you display the string, otherwise the linebreaks in the HTML source will just be ignored.